# Accessing elasticsearch on Heroku/Bonsai with an open source client

Tags: heroku, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

This short passage from Heroku, states that a myriade of clients can be used to integrate to you Bonsai-es instance. I've tried out es-head and elastic hammer but with no luck.

"The Bonsai add-on provides an ElasticSearch index to your application, which is available to any language and platform that can send JSON to its RESTful HTTP API. You may also opt to use one of the many open source ElasticSearch clients for tighter integration with languages and frameworks such as, in no particular order, Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Python, Django, PHP, Erlang, Clojure, Java, Play! and Perl."

Here is the es link I get from heroku for my instance:
http://xxxxxxx:yyyyyyyy@cypress-zzzzzzz.eu-west-2.bonsai.io

How would you get any of the below clients to connect to such an instance? or any other client for that matter...

---

http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/

http://elastichammer.exploringelasticsearch.com/

---

also, I noticed the following:

any attempt from es-head to call an es command returns a status code of 404

- my-es-server/_cluster/health
- my-es-server/_cluster/state
- my-es-server/_cluster/nodes
- my-es-server/_cluster/nodes/stats?all=true

is this due to a non correct login to the server? or are the commands "turned off"?

the 404 is followed with this message:
{
error: "Resource not found. Please contact support@bonsai.io for assistance.",
status: 404
}

Comment: I've created a support case about this at heroku/bonsai. I'll post any solution/response here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response i've got is that these es api calls are turned off for security reason. A complete access can be achieved by purchasing a complete platform.